# WSL2 unable to access internet when connecting to citrix secure access vpn

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, citrix

I have this issue with WSL2.0. Everytime I connect to my Citrix Secure Access VPN, my Ubuntu WSL2.0 loses internet connectivity. I cannot ping `www.afr.com.au` and I cannot ping `8.8.8.8`.

When I run `ping www.afr.com.au`, it results in:

> ping: [www.afr.com.au](http://www.afr.com.au): Temporary failure in name resolution

I do get an IP address of `172.31.176.8`. My `cat /etc/resolv.conf` is as below:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 192.168.152.221
nameserver 192.168.152.231
nameserver 172.19.96.1
search companya.com.au.local
```

My vEthernet(WSL) is `172.31.176.1`.

When i tried to `traceroute www.yahoo.com`, it returns:

> [www.yahoo.com](http://www.yahoo.com): Temporary failure in name resolution Cannot handle
> "host" cmdline arg 'www.yahoo.com' on position 1 (argc 1)

My /etc/wsl.conf is:

```
[network]
generateResolvConf = false
```

In my windows 10 cmd, when I try to run `nslookup` (whilst connected to VPN) it returns:
[image: nslookup]

I also already tried to turn off firewall in Windows Defender firewall settings, only for vEthernet WSL:
[image: Windows Defender]

Below is the result of `Get-NetIPInterface`:
[image: Get-NetIPInterface]